# Mock JwtDecoder in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-security, spring-test

This is the code in my service class method to get the JWT token based on the auth token passed.

```
        NimbusJwtDecoder decoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder) JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(userTokenUrl);
        Jwt jwt = decoder.decode(authResponse.authenticationResult().idToken());
        Map<String, Object> claims = jwt.getClaims();
        if(!ACTIVE.equals(claims.get(CUSTOM_STATUS).toString())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("User is not active");
        }
```

I want to write a JUnit for this service class method. Below approach I have tried but giving error while trying to decode token id **IllegalArgumentException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Signed JWT rejected: Another algorithm expected, or no matching key(s) found**

```
    NimbusJwtDecoder decoder = mock(NimbusJwtDecoder.class);
    when(decoder.decode(ArgumentMatchers.anyString()))
            .thenReturn(Jwt.withTokenValue(getToken()).header("typ", "JWT").header("alg", "HS256").claim("custom:status", "active").build());
```

Comment: You are following a wrong approach, your "business code" shouldn't know what you are using to secure your application. Only the "security functionality" needs to deal with it and, after verify it, convert it in the internal standar user information you can use in the rest of your code. In that way, you will be able to use `@WithMockUser` and similar annotations to write your tests. Spring provides a lot of functionality to help you with it and there are several online tutorials to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is feasible solution but this works for me. I refactor my code by extracting my jwt decoder code. I created a new method returning me Jwt object.

```
public Jwt getJwt(InitiateAuthResponse authResponse) {
    NimbusJwtDecoder decoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder) JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(userTokenUrl);
    return decoder.decode(authResponse.authenticationResult().idToken());
}
```

I am mocking this method in my test class.

```
    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer token");
    headers.put("typ", "JWT");
    headers.put("alg", "none");

    Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
    claims.put("custom:status", "active");
    
    Jwt jwt = new Jwt("fake-token", Instant.now(), Instant.now().plusSeconds(100), headers, claims);
    doReturn(jwt).when(spyService).getJwt(ArgumentMatchers.any());
```